# UIWebView size changes unexpectedly when load page on internet

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Here is the UIWebView in StoryBoard, but its content size changes when load a page from internet, i dont the problem is

[image: Story Board]

Here is it runing on iPhone, its content size is diffrent from `UIWebView`size. Is there something i did wrong?
[image]
[image]

This html page should look like this
[image]

and now is this
[image]

Comment: No, this is fine. The content size is defined by the content of the web page you're loading. Each web page will have different sizes. What exactly is bothering you about this?

Comment: @GuyKogus I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the top constraint incorrectly. You've set the `top` attribute of the web view to match the `bottom` attribute of the `Top Layout Guide`, instead of its bottom. Try and change that.

If it doesn't work then don't set it to match the `Top Layout Guide`, but instead the root `view`. To do this, when selecting the constraints hold the `alt` button and it should give you the option to create the constraint against the `Container Margin`.

Comment: I make it matches view